# How to customize Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a web application with Microsoft Application Insights. And I monitor all the requests, exceptions, perfomance, etc.

Is it possible to customize and disable the monitor of some requests?

I'd like to disable the monitor of some types of static files, like *.js, *.css, *.png.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. One of your options is to use a telemetry filter. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering). An example that filters out requests based on a url is this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// A Telemetry filter lets you define whether a telemetry item is dropped or not
/// </summary>
public class CustomTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public CustomTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // Example: process all telemetry except requests to .png files
        var isRequestToUrlContainingSpecificText = item is RequestTelemetry request && request.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".png");

        if (!isRequestToUrlContainingSpecificText)
            _next.Process(item); // Process the item
        else
        {
            // Item is dropped here
        }
    }
}
```

On the frontend you can also define a filter to stop telemetry from being send if it matches spcific criteria , see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#javascript-web-applications)

```js
var filteringFunction = (envelope) => {
  if (envelope.data.someField === 'tobefilteredout') {
      return false;
  }

  return true;
};

...


appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(filteringFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [vivek nuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527049/vivek-nuna),  after applying this setting

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
```

You can also enable AJAX request collection alltogether by using this setting:

```
disableAjaxTracking: false
```

Where
dableAjaxTracking: [boolean] - If true, Ajax calls are not autocollected.

Comment: This will stop all telemetry from being send, instead of being able to filter based on specific criteria.